# How to analyse binary responses for various factors, including interactions: chi square, mixed models, logistic regression, or ANOVA on percentages?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, anova, chi-squared-test, binary-data

I run an experiment where subject had to recognize an emotion from various musical stimuli (which were composed with a certain emotional intent). There were 4 levels of emotional_intent, subjects  results of a forced choice task were either 1 for correct, and 0 for wrong. There were 2 groups of participants, musicians and non-musicians.
So the dependent variable is binary, the within subject factor is emotional_intent with 4 levels, and the between subject factor is musical_expertise.
My goal is to understand whether there are differences in the recognition

1. between groups overall,
2. between emotions,
3. between groups within each emotional_intent level.

What is the best way to analyze the data? I considered these options:

1. Chi square: I compare the number of correct and wrong answers for the groups, and for the emotions, and for the interaction of these two factors.
   That seems simple, but what are the disadvantages here?
2. Use a mixed effect model and use post hoc test on the factors and interaction term
   Here I got a problem because being the answers either 0 or 1, the data are clearly not normally distributed. So the use of the anova on the fitted model resulting from the mixed effect would break the normality assumption. Am I correct, or can I still use the mixed effect model?

This is what I would use in R:

```r
library(lmerTest)
fit <- lmer(correct ~ emotional_intent* musical_expertise + 
            (1|subject), data=scrd)
anova(fit)

# Post hoc of the interaction term
emmeans(fit, pairwise~emotional_intent*musical_expertise, 
    adjust = "tukey")
```

3. Use a binomial logistic regression followed by an ANOVA:
   Here I could do an ANOVA on a model fitted using a binomial logistic regression, and then I can compute the post hoc tests on that model:

```r
model <- glm(correct ~ emotional_intent * musical_expertise, 
    family=binomial(link='logit'), data=scrd)
anova(model, test="Chisq")

# Post hoc of the interaction term
emmeans(model, pairwise~emotional_intent*musical_expertise, 
    adjust = "tukey")
```

4. I calculate the percentage of correct answers for each subject, then I compute a two-way ANOVA with repeated measures and the usual post-hoc tests. Here data are normally distributed, and assumptions are not violated. However, using the method at step 2, I get that there is actually statistical significance in the interaction term and in the related pairwise comparisons of the posthoc test.

Which method is more correct to use and why?
Are there other methods?

Comment: How many statistics courses have you taken?  What books have you read?

Comment: Published about 100 papers. is that enough for you? Is there someone willing to truly help?

Comment: I think what @Frank is probing for is some clues about what statistical facts and concepts we may assume in our answers and what we would have to explain.  Although it's nice you have published papers, that doesn't really help us in that regard.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand why. My question may be relevant for newbies, or other having similar troubles. I am not a statician but a computer scientist. I did an experiment and I am asking for an advise on how to best analyze it. So far my best guess is that the binomial logistic regression followed by an ANOVA with chi square distribution is the best approach. However I put on the table the various options I considered, as others could have the same troubles. So, I repeat, is there anybody willing to provide an help on this matter?

Comment: What you are describing as a post hoc of the interaction term is actually simply comparisons of the four cell predictions, wherein both marginal effects and interaction effects are in play. If you need all 6 of those comparisons, fine. But you might consider doing just the four simple (non-diagonal) comparisons.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RussLenth, yes I need those comparisons indeed. So do you agree that using the binomial logistic regression model and then performing this post hoc test:  emmeans(model, pairwise~emotional_intent*musical_expertise, adjust = "tukey") is the right way?

Comment: I agree a logistic model is a better choice than the lmer() model. But there is also the possiblity of using glmer(), wherein you can account for subject variations. There is also the possibility of a GEE model. Somebody besides me could comment on the relative merits of these methods, but I do think it's important to account for the subject effects.

Comment: Thanks @RussLenth. I wonder why it is crucial to account for the random effect of subjects in my case, considering this binomial logistic regression. So, using the lme4 package the formula should be : ```model <- glmer(correct ~emotional_intent*musical_expertise + (1|subject),family=binomial(link='logit'),data=scrd)``` , correct?

Comment: Subjects are part of the design, and it is reasonable to expect that they will not all respond the same.

Answer (score 0):

The study on the various techniques mentioned in the original question above led me to conclude that the right approach is a binomial logistic regression with subject as a random effects. The R code I used is the following

```r
library(lme4)
model <- glmer(correct ~ emotional_intent * musical_expertise + 
               (1|subject), family=binomial(link='logit'),
               data=scrd)
summary(model)

car::Anova(model) 

library(emmeans)
# Post hoc of the interaction term
emmeans(model, pairwise ~ emotional_intent * musical_expertise, 
        adjust = "tukey")
```